# remote true does not works in update method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I have this code...

```
    <%= simple_form_for my_object, url: object_path(object_id), html: {class: "form account-form"}, remote: true do |f| %>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
                <%= f.input :numero_matricula, label: "Núm. de Matricula" %>    
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
          <%= f.input :rg, label: "Rg", required: true %>   
        </div>
        <%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn-default', disabled: false %>
    <% end %>
```

When i click at the submit button, the request is html, but i need to call the update.js.erb. In my applicatin.js i have this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require icheck
//= require chosen
//= require jquery.mask
//= require jquery.maskMoney
//= require bootstrap
//= require smart_listing
//= require bootstrapValidator
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.pt-BR
//= require editable/bootstrap-editable
//= require editable/rails
//= require_tree .
```

This is the controller:

```
class FuncionariosController < ApplicationController  
   respond_to :html, :json, :js  

   def update
    @Object = Funcionario.find(params[:id])
    @object.update_attributes(params[:object])
   end
end
```

does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

If you need more information I am available...

Comment: Can you add the controller action that this is posting to?

Comment: This is strange - do you see any errors in the JS console?

Comment: no error in the console, and the strange thing is that I have another similar entity that works perfectly with the ajax request

Comment: The only thing that I can think of then is the rails ujs helpers are being overridden somewhere in your edit view, and so are not adding the submit handlers for the form.

Comment: thanks a lot @roo, i will check that!